# data transfer problem between qthread and ui?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I succeeded in creating a gui crawling program using Beautiful Soup and PyQt5.

By the way, I had a problem with gui freeze while the program executed the repeating statement.
So I'm going to use QThread.

But when I bring the elements related to gui on Thread, there is a problem.
(There's no problem with operating code that has nothing to do with gui, so I don't think there's any data transmission between classes.) (Is this right?)

I've created a simple problem. ↓

[image: Program Execution Screen]

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


form_class = uic.loadUiType('aaaa.ui')[0]


class Thread1(QThread):
def __init__(self, Main):
    super().__init__(Main)

def run(self):
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        print(self.lineEdit.text().strip()) #No data transmission between Main and Thread1??
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1


class Main(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initSetting()
        self.initSignal()


    def initSetting(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Wait')
        self.setWindowTitle('aaaa')


    def initSignal(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printWord)


    def printWord(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Threading')

        x = Thread1(self)
        x.start()



if __name__ == "__main__" :

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aaaa = Main()
    aaaa.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `QThread`, from what I understand, transmission of information between classes is doable, but to transmit information from your `Main` class to your `Thread1` class, you have to pass arguments upon instantiation of your `Thread1` class from your `Main` class.

In other words, your `Main` class and your `Thread1` class do not share any variables or functions. They are separate classes.

Here's how I might do this:

```
class Main(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initSetting()
        self.initSignal()

    def initSetting(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Wait")
        self.setWindowTitle("aaaa")

    def initSignal(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printWord)

    def printWord(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Threading")
        some_message = self.lineEdit.text().strip()
        self.thread_1 = Thread1(some_message)
        self.thread_1.start()


class Thread1(QThread):
    def __init__(self, input_message, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.input_message = input_message

    def run(self):
        i = 1
        while i <= 10:
            print(self.input_message)
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
```

Let me know if this is helpful.